# Sencha Android native packaging using eclipse

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I have created basic Application using Sencha Touch 2. Now I want to create .apk file. I tried using AndroidSDK Tool but couldn't get it done.

Can anyone tell me step by step process how I can create .apk file using eclipse. I already have installed ADT plugins.

How to generate .apk file for my sencha touch 2 application using eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Check out: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android
It explains how to package a native android application through commandline.
Seems quite simple. Haven't tried it out yet my self. It requires the Sencha SDK Tools.